# Why do we struggle to be good

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

Why is our whole life a struggle? At least from my observations we never move on to the "next level". The yetzer hara keeps giving us the same taavot and obstructions to improving ourselves and we never seem to make any progress. I don't think life is a video game, but why can't we get over our problems?

In other words, does struggling in our avodah equal failure in some part?

Comment: The struggle is valuable, which is a big part of the teachings of Tanya Likkutei Amarim.

Comment: My experience is very different. Repeated efforts over long periods of time always deliver results, whether it is to change life's habits, lose weigh, learn Torah, etc. Maybe you need to give things a bit longer to improve

Comment: @RabbiKaii I suppose then that I shouldn't expect an answer if that is the premise of an entire sefer

Comment: @mbloch small victories we may win. Though there is still that eternal struggle.

Comment: @Shababnik it might be hard to give a well justified answer, but I am not saying that. I'm saying read Tanya :)

Comment: If everything you ever wanted were handed to you on a silver platter before you even had time to wish for it, would you be satisfied?  No.  It's the road to get there that makes life worth living.